# How to create a dropdown menu for the user that has a session initiated

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the bootstrap navbar and its working fine, on mobile devices the toggle button appears and when this button is clicked it appears a dropdown with the correct menu items, just like the bootstrap default.

But i want also to have a menu item with the username that appears when a user has a session started, and when this menu item is clicked it appears also a dropdown menu with the items available to a user with a session initiated.

The menu items available to a user with a session initiated are:

```
<ul>
  <li>Edit Profile</li>
  <li>Logout</li>
</ul>
```

Do you know how to use the bootstrap to create that dropdown menu with the above items for the user with a session start? So that when the menu item "Jan" is clicked apperas a dropdown menu with the items above using the bootstrap styles just like when the toggle button in mobile device is clicked it appears the dropdown with the menu items?

Working example wihout that part of show the dropdown menu items available for a user with a session initiated working properly: https://jsfiddle.net/eeeoft8n/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), there are some great examples there.

you'll want to add the add the `div` with the `dropdown-menu` class and the necessary `aria-toggle` on the link to activate them.

```css
.menu_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

div.dropdown-menu{
  left:auto;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <a href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_nav" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="menu_container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex align-items-lg-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 0</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Jan
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete brains</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

*you might need to go fullscreen in order to get the full-width view instead of the mobile view*